# How do I spend a non-standard P2SH transaction

Tags: p2sh, bcoin

I was sent a P2SH puzzle address. I have solved the puzzle, which is to say I have created a script that matches the hash, and I know what to put on the stack before the script. Sadly, what I am having trouble figuring out is how to actually create a valid transaction with this non-standard script and no signature. All the examples and documentation I've found only talk about creating standard signature-based transactions and not ones with arbitrary scripts.

For example, let's say the encoded script is `955787` and someone actually sent bitcoin to the P2SH address for that script, which is `3PijzLhTnkA9S2HDFLrdwX9SCg69W8ggD4`

Now I want to spend that by providing the full redeem script:

```
1 7 955787
```

or I guess more accurately

```
OP_1 OP_7 3 0x955787
```

How do I actually create that transaction using `bitcoind` or `bcoin`? I don't see how to get it to create a transaction with that supplied script or transmit it to the network without a signature. I am looking for a list of command-line commands to run (use placeholders for any required data I did not supply above).

Comment: This is `standard` behavior/script/transaction. it is even not too difficult to create a transaction manually and/or write a tool for it. I think `importaddress "955787" "3PijzLhTnkA9S2HDFLrdwX9SCg69W8ggD4" false` will help

Answer (score 3):

First thing I noticed was the redeemScript, it's using `OP_MUL` which is disabled and you won't be able to use it in scripts.
But I can show it using `OP_ADD`.

If you want to play with `bcoin` and test the scripts, how they validate you can use `bcoin.script`:

### Verify and play with scripts

```
const scriptSig = new Script();
scriptSig.pushInt(6);
scriptSig.pushInt(1);
scriptSig.compile();
```

or you can assemble it using just string

```
const scriptSig = Script.fromString('OP_6 OP_1');
```

Now pubkeyScript  (redeemScript in P2SH)

```
const scriptPubkey = Script.fromRaw('935787', 'hex');
```

Or more verbose

```
const scriptPubkey = Script.fromString('OP_ADD OP_7 OP_EQUAL');
```

You can use `bcoin.stack` to run these scripts

```
const stack = new Stack();
scriptSig.execute(stack);
scriptPubkey.execute(stack);

// Verify the script was successful in its execution:
assert(stack.length === 1);
assert(stack.getBool(-1) === true);
```

### Redeem transaction

Back to the question:

```
const redeemScript = Script.fromRaw('935787', 'hex');
const address = Address.fromScripthash(redeemScript.hash160());
const sendto = Address.fromString('sendtoaddress');

// generate script with redeem
const script = new Script();
script.pushInt(6);
script.pushInt(1);
script.push(Opcode.fromPush(redeemScript.toRaw()));
script.compile();


// We received some transaction
// lets say coinbase
const cb = new MTX();

// Add a typical coinbase input
cb.addInput({
  prevout: new Outpoint(),
  script: new Script()
});

cb.addOutput({
  address: address,
  value: Amount.fromBTC('5').toValue()
});

const coin = bcoin.coin.fromTX(cb, 0, -1);

// From here we spend the transaction
const spend = new MTX();

spend.addCoin(coin);
spend.addOutput(sendto, Amount.fromBTC('4.9999').toValue());

spend.inputs[0].script = script;

assert(spend.verify());

// You can broadcast raw transaction
console.log(spend.toRaw().toString('hex'));
```